# How to prove that generating function of series ($1 ,\binom{m}{1},\binom{m+1}{2},\binom{m+2}{3},...$ ) equals $\frac{1}{(1-z)^m}$ .

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

How to prove that generating function of series ($1 ,\binom{m}{1},\binom{m+1}{2},\binom{m+2}{3},...$ ) equals $\frac{1}{(1-z)^m}$ .

How do I do this? I know that I have to use some differentiation somewhere  but what series do I use to start?

Comment: Are you supposed to know the binomial expansion $(1+u)^\alpha$  for that?

Comment: Yes actually, why not

Comment: I doubt that anyone would teach binomial coefficients and ask such a question without mentioning the binomial theorem along the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a couple of preliminary notes before we get to the proof.

> **Lemma**
>
> $$\sum_{i=k}^n\binom{i}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}$$

**Proof of Lemma**

The RHS counts the number of $k+1$ element subsets of $U=\{0\,\dotsc, n\}$. The RHS counts the same thing as the number of $k+1$ element subsets of $U$ with maximum element $i$ is $\binom{i}{k}$.$\blacksquare$

**Note on Multiplication of Formal Power Series**

In general if
$$
A(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}a_n x^n;\quad B(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}b_n x^n
$$
are two formal power series then their product is given by
$$
A(x)B(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}\left(\sum_{k=0}^na_kb_{n-k}\right)x^n.
$$
In particular since $(1-x)^{-1}=\sum_{n\geq 0} x^n$, it follows that
$$
A(x)(1-x)^{-1}=\sum_{n\geq0}\left(\sum_{k=0}^na_k\right)x^n\tag{1}
$$
**The Problem**

> We claim that
>   $$
> (1-z)^{-m}=\sum_{n\geq0}\binom{m+n-1}{n}z^{n} \quad (m\ge 1)
> $$

**Proof by Induction**

The base case holds since
$$
(1-z)^{-1}=\sum_{n\geq0} z^n=\sum_{n\geq0}\binom{1+n-1}{n}z^n
$$
as desired. Suppose that the result holds for all integers at most $m$. Then
$$
(1-z)^{-m-1}=(1-z)^{-m}\times(1-z)^{-1}=\sum_{n\geq0}\left(
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{m+k-1}{k}
\right)
x^n
$$
by (1) and the induction hypothesis. But
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{m+k-1}{k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{m+k-1}{m-1}=\sum_{i=m-1}^{n+m-1}\binom{i}{m-1}=\binom{n+m}{m}=\binom{m+n}{n}
$$
as desired where we have used the lemma.

Comment: In induction you used fact that any finite set has a maximum right? Using induction checking n+1 element would be the same right? Also in proof of Lema you used two RHS's

Comment: Also at the end of proof, why $k = m-1$ in sum of binomials?

Answer (score 4):

One way is to take $\frac{1}{1-z} = 1 + z + z^2 + \cdots$ and raise both sides to the $m$th power. To find the coefficient of $z^k$ in the resulting series, you need to solve a combinatorics problem (the [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) approach may help).

Another way is to start with $\frac{1}{1-z} = 1 + z + z^2 + \cdots$, differentiate both sides $m - 1$ times, and do some rearranging.

Comment: What do you mean by "differentiate" $m-1$ times? And why start exactly with $\frac{1}{1-z}$ ?

Comment: @Michał I mean take the derivative of $\frac{1}{1-z}$ (and the right-hand side) $m-1$ times.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the fact that the coefficient of $z^n$ in the  power series expansion  near $0$ of a holomorphic function $f(z)$ is equal to $\;\dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$.

For $f(z)=\dfrac1{(1-z)^m}$, we see by an easy induction that
\begin{alignat}{2}
&&\biggl(\frac1{(1-z)^m}\biggr)^{\mkern-5mu(n)}&=\frac{m(m+1)\dotsm(m+n-1)}{(1-z)^{m+n}},\\
&\text{so }&f^{(n)}(0)&=m(m+1)\dotsm(m+n-1)=\frac{(m+n-1)!}{(m-1)!}\\
&\text{and eventually}\mkern-20mu &\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}&=\frac{(m+n-1)!}{(m-1)!\:n!}=\binom{m+n-1}{n}.
\end{alignat}

Comment: Where does $(\frac1{(1-z)^m})^{\mkern-5mu(n)}$=$\frac{m(m+1)\dotsm(m+n-1)}{(1-z)^{m+n}},$ come from? I can't really understand this anwser, I didn't really learn holomorphic functions at university and I probably won't, thanks for your anwser though

Comment: Replace `holomorphic` by `infinitely differentiable` (for complex functions, it's the same, and the power series expansion is  Taylor's series. As to  how one obtains the r.h.s., it's by induction. The only formula you have to know to obtain ii in a quick way is that $\;\biggl(\dfrac1{1-z)^r}\biggr)'=\dfrac{-r}{(1-z)^{r+1}}\cdot(-1)$.

Comment: Alright then, I have Taylor's series for $z^{n}$ at point $a=0$ will be $f(z) = f(0) + \frac{f^{'}(0)}{1!} *z + \frac{f^{''}(0)}{2!} *z^{2} +... $. First question, why why does it sum up into $\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$  and second question, why do we choose exactly point 0 not other point

Comment: For the first question, I don't what ‘sums up’. I only calculated the generic term and coefficient (those for degree $n$). As to the second question, this is the standard choice, as we know the disk of convergence ($|z|<1$);

Comment: I meant does this taylor series that I wrote equals $\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$

Comment: The sum of the Taylor series is $f(z)=\dfrac1{(1-z)^m}$ and  $\;\dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$ is simply the coefficient of $z^n$ in the Taylor series.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{m + k - 1 \choose k}z^{k} & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\overbrace{{-\bracks{m + k - 1} + k - 1 \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}}^{\ds{Negating\ \mbox{the Binomial}}}\,\,\,
z^{k} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{-m \choose k}\pars{-z}^{k}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{\rule{0pt}{4mm}1 + \pars{-z}}^{\, -m} = \bbx{1 \over \pars{1 - z}^{m}}
\end{align}